# Trying to create a generic method to avoid repetition of code

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am working on a C# application, and I have 2 (soon to be 3, 4 and more) methods which have such a similar structure they are begging to be converted to something more generic. Here are 2 samples, you will see the similarities.

**Method 1:**

```
 public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> McaEventStoreRecvdPointsCouponProxyResponse(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string thisRequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            if (request.PathParameters.Any())
            {
                var cardNumber = request.PathParameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.ToLower() == "card_number").Value;
                context.Logger.LogLine($"MCA Event store event [{cardNumber}]");

                var restValueVoucher = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectRestValueVoucherPayload>(request.Body);
                RestValueVoucherPayloadValidator validator = new RestValueVoucherPayloadValidator();
                ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(restValueVoucher.Payload);

                if (!results.IsValid) throw new SchemaValidationException(results.Errors);

                var dbRestValueVoucher = restValueVoucher.Payload.Convert(restValueVoucher.Payload);

                dbRestValueVoucher.CardNumber = cardNumber;
                loyaltyContext.Add(dbRestValueVoucher);
                int rowsAffected = await loyaltyContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                context.Logger.LogLine($"Database changes applied {rowsAffected}");

                return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new EventStoreResponse(context,
                    RequestResponseTypes.EVENT_STORE, thisRequestId,
                    restValueVoucher.Payload));
            }
            else
            {
                return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new TestResponse(context, RequestResponseTypes.TEST_REQUEST));
            }
        }
        catch (SchemaValidationException schemaEx)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine(schemaEx.Message);
            return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, schemaEx);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"{ex}");

            LcsException lcsException = new LcsException(ex);
            return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                lcsException);
        }
    }
```

**Method 2:**

```
    public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> McaEventStoreTierChangeProxyResponse(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string thisRequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            if (request.PathParameters.Any())
            {
                var cardNumber = request.PathParameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.ToLower() == "card_number").Value;
                context.Logger.LogLine($"MCA Event store event [{cardNumber}]");

                var tierChange = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectTierChangePayload>(request.Body);
                TierChangePayloadValidator validator = new TierChangePayloadValidator();
                ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(tierChange.Payload);

                if (!results.IsValid) throw new SchemaValidationException(results.Errors);

                var dbTierChange = tierChange.Payload.Convert(tierChange.Payload);
                dbTierChange.CardNumber = cardNumber;
                loyaltyContext.Add(dbTierChange);
                int rowsAffected = await loyaltyContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                context.Logger.LogLine($"Database changes applied {rowsAffected}");

                return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new EventStoreResponse(context,
                    RequestResponseTypes.EVENT_STORE, thisRequestId,
                    tierChange.Payload));
            }
            else
            {
                return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new TestResponse(context, RequestResponseTypes.TEST_REQUEST));
            }
        }
        catch (SchemaValidationException schemaEx)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine(schemaEx.Message);
            return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, schemaEx);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"{ex}");

            LcsException lcsException = new LcsException(ex);
            return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                lcsException);
        }
    }
```

I started to work on the generic method, and got this far:

```
    private static TPayload ProcessTest<TPayload, TEvent>(TPayload payload, TEvent myevent, string body, AbstractValidator<TPayload> validator)
        where TPayload : Payload
        where TEvent : IEventStore
    {
        var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TPayload>(body);
        ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(?)
    }
```

My issue is with refactoring this line at the moment: ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(tierChange.Payload). tierChange is a JSON 'Root object' that allows me to accept incoming JSON in the following format:

```
{
  "Message": {
    "message-id": 1000,
    "old-tier": "SISTERCLUB",
    "new-tier": "DIAMOND",
    "timestamp-of-change": "2020-07-27T00:00:00",
    "anniversary-date": "2020-07-28T00:00:00"
  }
}
```

The structure is very similar to the incoming JSON for Method 1, which is:

```
{
  "Message": {
      "message-id": 10000,
      "redeemed-voucher-instance-id":123,
      "new-voucher-instance-id":1234,
      "initial-voucher-value": 5.00,
      "rest-voucher-value":15.00,
      "valid-from": "2020-07-27T00:00:00",
      "valid-to": "2021-07-27T00:00:00",
      "description": "$5 BIRTHDAY VOUCHER",
      "unit": "AUD"
  }
}
```

The .Payload is used to access the content inside the root object in both cases, (content which is unique to each object). Here is an example of the Tier Change Root object and Payload (apart from different properties within Payload, the other object is the same).

The root object:

```
public class RootObjectTierChangePayload 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Message")]
    public TierChangePayload Payload { get; set; }
}
```

And the inner object:

```
 public partial class TierChangePayload : Payload, ITransform<TierChangePayload, TierChange>, IEventStore 
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "message-id")]
        public int MessageId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "old-tier")]
        public string OldTier { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "new-tier")]
        public string NewTier { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "timestamp-of-change")]
        public DateTime TimestampOfChange { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "anniversary-date")]
        public DateTime AnniversaryDate { get; set; }

        public TierChange Convert(TierChangePayload source)
        {
            TierChange tierChange = new TierChange
            {
                CreatedTimestamp = Functions.GenerateDateTimeByLocale(),
                ChangeTimestamp = null,
                AnniversaryDate = this.AnniversaryDate,
                MessageId = this.MessageId,
                NewTierId = this.NewTier,
                OldTierId = this.OldTier
            };

            return tierChange; 
        }

        public string ToJson()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

How can I adjust the objects I'm using so that I can better generalise them to suit the generic method? At the moment, I can't access *.Payload* in the generic method.

Comment: `class RootObjectTierChangePayload : IWithPayload` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
In C# you can pass code blocks (delegates) to other code blocks as `Action<T>` type or `Func<T>` type (with a variable number of generic arguments).
Those types just encapsulate your code and are useful in the cases such as yours - where the method is almost the same save for a couple of lines. You can take those couple of lines and pass them as a parameter to the method.

`Action<>` is a code block that takes T arguments and returns `void`.
`Func<>` is a code block that takes 0 or several T1 arguments and returns a T result.

Note that when compiled, these code blocks turn into static methods, and are thus purely a syntactic sugar.

**End update**

So your generic method can look like this:

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> GenericMethod<T>(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context, Func<string, (T, ValidationResult, string)> validationFunc) where T: class
{
    try
    {
        string thisRequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        if (request.PathParameters.Any())
        {
            var cardNumber = request.PathParameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.ToLower() == "card_number").Value;
            context.Logger.LogLine($"MCA Event store event [{cardNumber}]");

            var validationAndData = validationFunc(request.Body);
            ValidationResult results = validationAndData.Item2;

            if (!results.IsValid) throw new SchemaValidationException(results.Errors);

            loyaltyContext.Add(validationAndData.Item1);
            int rowsAffected = await loyaltyContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Database changes applied {rowsAffected}");

            return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new EventStoreResponse(context,
                RequestResponseTypes.EVENT_STORE, thisRequestId,
                validationAndData.Item3));
        }
        else
        {
            return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
             new TestResponse(context, RequestResponseTypes.TEST_REQUEST));
        }
    }
    catch (SchemaValidationException schemaEx)
    {
        context.Logger.LogLine(schemaEx.Message);
        return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, schemaEx);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        context.Logger.LogLine($"{ex}");

        LcsException lcsException = new LcsException(ex);
        return GenerateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            lcsException);
    }
}
```

Then you can convert the other two like so:

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> McaEventStoreRecvdPointsCouponProxyResponse(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
{
    return await GenericMethod(request, context, (body) => {
        var restValueVoucher = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectRestValueVoucherPayload>(request.Body);
        RestValueVoucherPayloadValidator validator = new RestValueVoucherPayloadValidator();
        var dbRestValueVoucher = restValueVoucher.Payload.Convert(restValueVoucher.Payload);
        dbRestValueVoucher.CardNumber = cardNumber;

        return (dbRestValueVoucher, validator.Validate(restValueVoucher.Payload), restValueVoucher.Payload);
    });
}

public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> McaEventStoreTierChangeProxyResponse(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
{
    return await  GenericMethod(request, context, (body) => {
        var tierChange = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObjectTierChangePayload>(request.Body);
            TierChangePayloadValidator validator = new TierChangePayloadValidator();
            var dbTierChange = tierChange.Payload.Convert(tierChange.Payload);
            dbTierChange.CardNumber = cardNumber;
            return (dbTierChange, validator.Validate(tierChange.Payload), tierChange.Payload);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi zaitsman, thank you for taking some time out to review my question. Would you mind expanding on why your use of Func<> both generally, and in this specific context? I've not used it before.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This has been a really useful answer, and it's appreciated.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you make generic root object

```
public class RootObject<T> 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Message")]
    public T Payload { get; set; }
}
```

It could work if the json can handle that.

```
var tierChange = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject<TPayload>>(request.Body);
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(tierChange.Payload);
```